# Can I write $|x|$ as $|-x|$?

Tags: real-analysis

I think it's wrong, because
$$|x|=\begin{cases} x&\text{, if }x\geq 0\\
        -x&\text{, if } x<0\end{cases},$$
but,
$$|-x|=\begin{cases}-x&\text{, if }x\geq 0\\
        x&\text{, if }x<0\end{cases}.$$

Is my proof correct?

Comment: We have $|x|=|-x|$ for all $x$.

Comment: Let $x=5$ and use your second equation to get $|-5|=-5$. This is the error.

Comment: You replaced the results on the second equation, but didn't replace the conditions (you need to do both).

Comment: All formulas with lots of minus signs and absolute value signs and $x$'s look much the same. When you write down a formula, it is useful to text it at least in one's head with a concrete number.

Comment: By the multiplicative property of absolute value, we have|-x| = |-1| * |x| = 1 * |x| = |x|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are wrong, $|-x|=-x$ if $-x\geq 0$ but you wrote $|-x|=-x$ if $x\geq 0$.

Comment: Yes. You wrote it. And it is wrong.

Comment: It must be "if $y\geq 0$"

Comment: Ok Ok thanks for your quick responds, just saw where I went wrong :)

Comment: if I let -x=y,
when  x>0 implies y<0
then |-x|=|y|=-y(bcs y<0),
then -y=x,
so finally |x|=|-x|=x (for x>0)......

Comment: Exactly, and $-y=x$ then $|-x|=x$ in that case.

Comment: Good, you got it.

Answer (score 4):

We will show that $|x|=|-x|$ for all $x$.

The result is obvious if $x=0$. We show it is true if $x\gt 0$.

If $x\gt 0$, then $|x|=x$. Also, if $x\gt 0$, then $-x\lt 0$, and therefore $|-x|=-(-x)=x$.
Thus we have shown that $|x|=|-x|$ if $x\gt 0$.

Now it is your turn. Complete the argument by showing that $|x|=|-x|$ if $x\lt 0$.

**Remark:** It is difficult to evaluate your argument.  The formulas dealing with $|-x|$ are not correct. And there are not enough words for one to know what was intended.

Comment: If x<0, then |x|=-x. Also, if x<0, then −x>0, and therefore |−x|=-x. Thus we have shown that |x|=|−x| if x<0.

Comment: Yes, that's it. We could gather the two separate arguments into a single one, since they are close relatives. But then one risks losing control over the logic.

Answer (score 2):

$|-x|=-x$ if $-x\geq 0 $ and $x$ if $-x\leq 0$

Answer (score 1):

It's like this:
$$|-x|=\begin{cases}-x&\text{, if }-x\geq 0\\
        x&\text{, if }-x<0\end{cases}.$$
which gives :

$$\begin{cases}x&\text{, if }x\geq 0\\
        -x&\text{, if }x<0\end{cases}.$$